Why do we require that all successors model this formula?
I'm reading Fitting's Intuitionistic Logic, Model Theory and Forcing. This occurs in Chapter 7.15.
The aim is to prove that a certain intuitionistic model is an intuitionistic model of ZF. I unfortunately don't think I can sum up what is happening to someone unfamiliar with the book at all, so I will simply post a screenshot of what Fitting does and hope someone here has worked through it before.

I'm concerned about this lemma that he states right at the beginning of the chapter (the image shows both the statement and the proof). I understand the proof completely, but I don't see why we require that $\Gamma^* \vDash ((t \in c_1) \leftrightarrow (t \in c_2))$ at all. After all, we're dealing with an intuitionistic Kripke model, so we could just require that $\Gamma \vDash ((t \in c_1) \leftrightarrow (t \in c_2))$ and this should follow immediately.
Fitting usually doesn't make an error like this and he actually repeats it on the next page and emphasizes it's important to look at every successor $\Gamma^*$, so I guess I must be missing something. The only thing I can think of is that the domain of $t$ changes throughout the model, but it really shouldn't, as all $t$-s are from a fixed $\rho_{\alpha_0}$.

No one seems to be replying and I'm now fairly certain of the answer, so I'll add this here for completeness.
This is probably just an error in the book. The author reinforces the fact that it is important to look at all the $\Gamma^*$ later on, but never actually uses the fact that $\Gamma^*$ should model the equivalence above. Instead, he checks that each $\Gamma^*$ models both $(t \in c_1)$ and $(t \in c_2)$ or neither --- but this is actually the condition I was talking about, namely that the original $\Gamma$ models that above equivalence.
What probably happened is that the author really wanted to stress that it is important to check all the $\Gamma^*$ here (and it is, that much is evident already from the intuitionistic interpretation of $\leftrightarrow$) and mistakenly put this statement as the one that needed to be checked, probably having a mental typo on the intuitionistic definition of $\leftrightarrow$.
I'm probably correct about this, but even if I'm wrong, the author's approach to the rest of the chapter doesn't actually change at all under my interpretation (he does everything correctly there, only invoking this lemma implicitly, which masks our disagreement), so it's not that big of a deal anyway.

Maybe you ask Melvin Fitting about it?

This is a very plausible explanation.

@მამუკაჯიბლაძე Hello! I actually emailed him, but he never got back to me. He seems to be retired, so it's understandable that he doesn't check that kind of stuff anymore. I don't have any other way to contact him.
